Frontend React application fails to fetch data from the backend API endpoint correctly, resulting in an AxiosError: Network Error status code 401
i am making fullstack course selling app , everything working fine but this one route in admin route does not,
UpdateCourse() component sends a get request to the backend to which has params /${courseID} and a config object which has headers authorization token ,the backend authenticate with the authentication middleware , it should return the course , and then i can update the course with input fields ,but i get an error
Error fetching course:

AxiosError {stack: "settle@http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/de…ost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js:2156:58", message: "Request failed with status code 401", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_..


the error fetching course comes from:
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching course:" , error);

everything works fine when i remove the authentication middleware in my backend route from the routes i am trying to access in this component , but the middleware is not the issue as other components works fine , i think there is some issue with sending params and headers in this axios request , in other routers i have only been sending auth header and it worked fine
 const config = {
        headers : {
        "Content-type" : "application/json" ,
        "Authorization" : `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('admin-course-auth')}` 
        }
    }

// this works fine , meaning the authentication middleware works fine
const response = await axios.get(http://localhost:3000/admin/courses/ , config)
//this works fine when i remove the authentication middleware from the backend route
const response = await axios.get(http://localhost:3000/admin/courses/${id}})
//this doesnt work fine , when i put the authentication middleware back :(
const response = await axios.get(http://localhost:3000/admin/courses/${id}} , config)
// this is my backend route :
app.get('/admin/courses/:id' ,authenticateJWTadmin, (req,res)=>{
  const id = parseInt(req.params.id)
  fs.readFile('courses.json' , 'utf-8' , (err,data)=>{
    if(err) throw err
    else{
      let courses = JSON.parse(data)
      let course = courses.find(course => course.id === id);
      if(course) return res.json(course)
        else res.status(404).json("course not found")
    }
  })
})

//this is my authentication middleware
const authenticateJWTadmin = (req,res,next)=>{
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if(authHeader){
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    req.token = token 
    jwt.verify(token , secretAdmin , (err,user)=>{
      if(err){
        return res.sendStatus(403)
      }
      req.user=user
      next();
    })
  }
  res.status(401)
}

//this is my hook for calling the function fetchCourse() which sends the axios request
 React.useEffect(()=>{
        async function checkAuthandFetchCourse(){
            const result = await isLoggedIn();
            setLogin(result);
            if(result){
                await fetchCourse();
            }
            else {
                navigate('/login')
            }
        }
        checkAuthandFetchCourse();
    }
    ,[id , navigate ])

//(i believe this is correct , because logging result returns true and isLoggedIn() is working correctly
//(hope i explained the problem well ,this is my first project learnig MERN , i might have made some silly mistake)
//update: using fetch fixes it


            const data = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/admin/courses/${id}` , {
                method : "GET" ,
                headers : {
                    "Content-type" : 'application/json',
                    "Authorization" : `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('admin-course-auth')}`
                }
            })
            const response = await data.json();



everything now works fine except console, it logs 401 unauthrized , idk why
